# SQL insert not inserting converted date format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert records from one table into another and convert varchar to a date format with type of 101 (mm/dd/yyyy). The wierd thing that happens is that once i run stored procedure the source table data format changes but the destination shows the old format of (yyyy-mm-dd)

Any suggestions. See stored procedure below

```
INSERT INTO Sales 
    (
        DEALER
        ,UW
        ,SKU
        ,SKU_DESCRIPTION
        ,EARNING_TYPE
        ,TERM
        ,PRODUCTPURCH
        ,CONTRACTPURCH
        ,ACCOUNTINGPURCH
        ,CONTRACTS_SUM
        ,PREMIUM
        ,RESERVE
        ,FEES
    )

SELECT TmpSales.[DEALER]
      ,TmpSales.[UW]
      ,TmpSales.[SKU]
      ,TmpSales.[SKU_DESCRIPTION]
      ,TmpSales.[EARNING_TYPE]
      ,TmpSales.[TERM]
      ,convert(date,TmpSales.[PRODUCTPURCH], 101) as PURCHDATE
      ,convert(date,TmpSales.[CONTRACTPURCH], 101) as CONPURCHDATE
      ,convert(date,TmpSales.[ACCOUNTINGPURCH], 101) as ACCDATE
      ,TmpSales.[CONTRACTS_SUM]
      ,(TmpSales.[RESERVE] + TmpSales.[FEES]) as PREMIUM
      ,TmpSales.[RESERVE]
      ,TmpSales.[FEES]
  FROM [dbo].[Tmp_Sales_Upld] as TmpSales
```

Comment: destination is not a string, it's a date. Date fields do not have a format. What you are seeing is the default format using to display data from date fields by the display tool. Since the data is a Date, you can display in any format you wish, use convert on the way out to convert it to a varchar in desired format.

Comment: Oops. did not see that one coming. Thank you Charles it has been a long day :-)

Comment: No worries, been there ....